# Where can I found a example database for apply data quality improvement?

Tags: sql-server

I am doing a little database improvement project, but I need a large database example.

Comment: How about the Stack Overflow database? https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/10/how-to-download-the-stack-overflow-database-via-bittorrent/

Comment: What size of the database you are looking for?

Comment: @SlavaMurygin, not too little and not too big. Between 500MB and 2GB is good.

Comment: Thanks. SO would be good. Or you can just double/triple AdventureWorks.

Answer (score 0):

[here](https://www.springboard.com/blog/free-public-data-sets-data-science-project/) we have some big public datasets I want to work with the million song Dataset some day. Also google offers some public [datasets](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/public-data/)

Enjoy them!!